# How to plot time series that consists of different dates but same timestamps on one graph in matplotlib

Tags: python, datetime, graph, matplotlib, plot

I have data that shows some values collected on three different dates: 2015-01-08, 2015-01-09 and 2015-01-12. For each date there are several data points that have timestamps.

Date/times are in a list and it looks as follows:

```
['2015-01-08-09:00:00', '2015-01-08-10:00:00', '2015-01-08-11:00:00', '2015-01-08-12:00:00', '2015-01-08-13:00:00', '2015-01-09-14:00:00', '2015-01-09-15:00:00', '2015-01-09-16:00:00', '2015-01-12-09:00:00', '2015-01-12-10:00:00', '2015-01-12-11:00:00']
```

On the other hand I have corresponding values (floats) in another list:

```
[12210.0, 12210.0, 12180.0, 12240.0, 12250.0, 12420.0, 12390.0, 12400.0, 12380.0, 12450.0, 12460.0]
```

To put all this together and plot a graph I use following code:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as md
import dateutil
from matplotlib.font_manager import FontProperties

timestamps = ['2015-01-08-09:00:00', '2015-01-08-10:00:00', '2015-01-08-11:00:00', '2015-01-08-12:00:00', '2015-01-08-13:00:00', '2015-01-09-14:00:00', '2015-01-09-15:00:00', '2015-01-09-16:00:00', '2015-01-12-09:00:00', '2015-01-12-10:00:00', '2015-01-12-11:00:00']

ticks = [12210.0, 12210.0, 12180.0, 12240.0, 12250.0, 12420.0, 12390.0, 12400.0, 12380.0, 12450.0, 12460.0]

plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.2)
plt.xticks( rotation=90 )

dates = [dateutil.parser.parse(s) for s in timestamps]

ax=plt.gca()
ax.set_xticks(dates)
ax.tick_params(axis='x', labelsize=8)

xfmt = md.DateFormatter('%H:%M:%S')
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(xfmt)

plt.plot(dates, ticks, label="Price")

plt.xlabel("Date and time", fontsize=12)
plt.ylabel("Price", fontsize=12)
plt.suptitle("Price during last three days", fontsize=12)

plt.legend(loc=0,prop={'size':8})

plt.savefig("figure.pdf")
```

When I try to plot these datetimes and values I get a messy graph with the line going back and forth.

It looks like the dates are being ignored and only timestamps are taken in account which is the reason for the messy chart. I tried to edit the datetimes to have the same date and consecutive timestamps and it fixed the chart. However, I must have dates as well..

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hi Aka, welcome to Stack Overflow! I removed your long introduction, you can repost it as a comment if you like, but it is not essential to the question. We try to keep only the important bits in the question so others finding it later can get right to the good stuff!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When I try to plot these datetimes and values I get a messy graph with the line going back and forth.

Your plots are going all over the place because `plt.plot` connects the dots in the order you give it. If this order is not monotonically increasing in x, then it looks "messy". You can sort the points by x first to fix this. Here is a minimal example:

```
import numpy as np
import pylab as plt

X = np.random.random(20)
Y = 2*X+np.random.random(20)

idx = np.argsort(X)
X2 = X[idx]
Y2 = Y[idx]

fig,ax = plt.subplots(2,1)
ax[0].plot(X,Y)
ax[1].plot(X2,Y2)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! The thing is, if I substitute the elements of my "timestamps" list with 1, 2, 3, 4, ... 11 then everything sorts out just fine. This lead me to conclude that python overlooks the dates and looks only at the time. Thus, it plots 09:00, 10:00 .. etc for one January 8 and then again goes back to 09:00, 10:00 .. etc for January 9 on the same spot on the X axis.

Comment: @Aka When I plotted the data you provided, hence why I tried to answer the stated question. I didn't see what you were talking about. Can you edit your question to provide a _minimal example_ with a _picture_? I know you can't post yet, put an imgur link up and we can edit it in for you.

Comment: What I want to do is to continuously plot Jan-8 09:00, Jan-8 10:00 ... etc .. Jan-9 09:00, Jan-9 10:00 ... Jan-12 09:00, Jan-12 10:00 etc. on x axis without having to break up my graph by dates. Is it possible to plot so that both dates AND times of day are taken in account?

Comment: It is, since `datetime` objects have an ordering relation between them. Did you try sorting the "dates" using the example I provided?

Comment: Haven't had a chance yet. But if you can see in the initial post the list is already pretty sorted and I don't know why it should need any additional sorting. Doesn't python take elements starting from the index=0 item?

Comment: I appreciate your help. Had to move on to some other part of the project and leave this problem alone for now. Thanks anyway!